# pyinstaller, import error: no module named pywintypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-prompt, pyinstaller

I want to create exe from a py script using pyinstaller. I wrote the following command in cmd "pyinstaller --onefile --windowed filename.py", but there is an error showed by the cmd. How do I solve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ..depend import bindepend
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ..utils.win32.winmanifest import RT_MANIFEST
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 97, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winresource
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pywintypes
ImportError: No module named pywintypes
```

Edit: I have tried to "pip install pypiwin32, but still got the same ImportError

Comment: As Traceback says, you haven't got module `pywintypes`. You must install this.

Comment: @R.Gadeev  I tried it and it said '  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywintypes (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywintypes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to work in a `virtualenv` if you are on Windows. I recommand [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-windows). You will be able to easily install most of python packages.

Once Anaconda is installed, just run `conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller=3.2.1`
 and you should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your help! I will use conda to install other library next time.

Answer (score 0):

In some case you have to manually mention modules that need to be packes through the keyword "--hidden-import

So in your case:
    pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-import=pywintypes --windowed filename.py

Comment: I tried it, but the result still the same.no module named pywintypes.

Comment: Does this error appear when you run the python script on your machine or only when you try to make an executable? In the first case you need to download it: 'pip install pypiwin32' in later case try the points mentioned here under ImportError: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/How-to-Report-Bugs

Comment: it is only when i tried to make an executable. I've tried to pip install pypiwin32, but it said that it already installed and tried the github, but the same thing still happen.