# Python: scrapy tutorial, import error nomodule named pywintypes

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, pywin32

I am new to `Scrapy` and tried to follow the tutorial from [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). When I tried to `run` it using `scrapy crawl quotes` in cmd. It show the below error message. How do I solve it?

```
2017-05-16 11:37:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.3.3 started (bot: 
tutorial)
2017-05-16 11:37:26 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: 
{'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': 
['tutorial.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2017-05-16 11:37:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2017-05-16 11:37:28 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

2017-05-16 11:37:28 [twisted] CRITICAL:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1301, 
in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 90, in crawl
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 97, in 
_create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in 
__init__
    self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\__init__.py", 
line 88, in __init__
    self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 58, in 
from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in 
from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 44, in 
load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "c:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\downloadermiddlewares\retry.py", line 20, in <module>
    from twisted.web.client import ResponseFailed
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\web\client.py", line 42, in 
<module>
    from twisted.internet.endpoints import HostnameEndpoint, wrapClientTLS
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\endpoints.py", line 
37, in <module>
    from twisted.internet.stdio import StandardIO, PipeAddress
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\stdio.py", line 30, 
in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _win32stdio
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_win32stdio.py", line 
18, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _pollingfile, main
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\_pollingfile.py", 
line 106, in <module>
    import pywintypes
ImportError: No module named pywintypes
```

I have encountered similar problem with `ImportError pywintypes` before using `pyinstaller` and have not found solution to it. I posted [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820342/pyinstaller-import-error-no-module-named-pywintypes/43820502?noredirect=1#comment74683276_43820502) on stackoverflow, too.

Comment: Have you try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254285/pyinstaller-importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes27-dll#answer-34123049?

Comment: @Tiny.D I tried copy the pywintypes but still got the same error and I tried to add the PATH but still got the same error.

Comment: do you restart your pc after the installation?

Comment: @Tiny.D no, I don't.

Comment: pls restart then try again

Comment: @Tiny.D I restarted my laptop and tried to run it again, but still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said in the [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#platform-specific-installation-notes), it is recommended to install scrapy on Windows with [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-windows). It's a `virtualenv`, so it will make a clean install of scrapy on your system, and all the dependencies will be automatically installed.

Once Anaconda is installed you enter this cmd in your console: `conda install -c conda-forge scrapy` and you should be fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have miniconda installed already, should I install Anaconda, too? or can i just enter those cmd in my console?

Comment: It works! thanks a lot! Can you please answer my other question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43820342/pyinstaller-import-error-no-module-named-pywintypes/43820502?noredirect=1#comment74683276_43820502)??